# ntp.conf error. unexpected T_String, expecting T_EOC

Tags: 14.04, server, ntp

Having a problem with my NTP server. It is an Ubuntu 14.04 VM. It seems to hang after a day or so of running. When it's up, it's working fine. I'm seeing these errors in syslog:

```
ntpd[901]: syntax error in /etc/ntp.conf line 37, column 19    
ntpd[901]: line 38 column 19 syntax error, unexpected T_String, expecting T_EOC
```

I though maybe it was a config issue, so I navigated to line 32 column 19 which was just the subnet mask entry. That makes no sense. So I searched the web, in which I found [a bug report](https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1406) on it, suggesting to rename `/etc/ntp.conf.rpmnew` to `/etc/ntp.conf`. Only problem is the file is already named `ntp.conf`. So dead end there. I'm a bit stumped. Any help would be very appreciated.

Here is the `ntp.conf` file.

```
#/etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift    
#Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/    

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats    
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable    
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable    
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable    

#Specify one or more NTP servers.

   server 0.us.pool.ntp.org    
   server 1.us.pool.ntp.org    
   server 2.us.pool.ntp.org    
   server 3.us.pool.ntp.org    



restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    
restrict 10.x.0.0 255.255.0.0 nomodify notrap    

#Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.    
restrict 127.0.0.1    
restrict ::1    

#If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
#(Again, the address is an example only.)    
broadcast 10.x.x.x
```

Comment: Line 37 or line 32? The posted file has only 35 lines. Is there a file named `ntp.conf.dpkg-dist`?

Comment: Because of the html formatting it will not line up exactly. The line it is pointing to is: restrict 10.x.0.0 **255**.255.0.0 nomodify notrap. Right at the beginning of 255. Sorry about the 37 or 32 confusion. I modified it and it changed.

Answer (score -1):

I've ran into the same error while setting up an NTP client on my Windows workstation.

It turns out, there was a typo in the 'server 127.127.20.1 ...' line, but not specifically in the column that the error referenced.

In my case, the typo was in the word minpoll, which I'd written as minipoll.
(server 127.127.20.1 minpoll 4 prefer)

Answer (score -1):

`ntpd` is reporting a syntax error "*right at the beginning of 255*" because, well, that's exactly where the syntax error is.

According to `ntp.conf(5)`, the proper syntax for the `restrict` command is:

```
restrict address[/cidr] [mask mask] [flag ...]
```

Compare that -- *very carefully* -- with the `restrict` commands in your `ntp.conf` file (hint: they're different), fix your `restrict` commands, and `ntpd` will quit complaining.

---

**Spoonfeeding:**

You need to either (1) add the missing "`mask`" keyword to your `restrict` commands or (2) modify your `restrict` commands to CIDR notation.

```
$ sed -i.bak -E -e 's/^(restrict 10.x.0.0) (255.255.0.0)/\1 mask \2/' /etc/ntp.conf
```

---

(On a side note, I'm quite curious why you thought it was necessary to obfuscate the **RFC1918** network addresses in your post. Obfuscating them required **more** effort and provided you with absolutely no benefit whatsoever.)